# remove wp- prefix using a php script

Tags: php, wp-admin, wp-config

I want to remove the wp- prefix from the wp-admin folder. I don't want to use a plugin, this because I want to code myself this wordpress hack. 
My question is, what files I need to edit after I've renamed the wp-admin folder? Is there any list out there that I can consult to know how many files are affected if the wp- prefix is removed from wordpress files and folders?

**UPDATE:**

I've reached the scope, [here](https://github.com/ziobru/no_prefix_WordPress_setup) is a working draft from github.

Comment: why do want to modify the wordpress core files?

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla I'm doing this for learning and research scopes.